# Getting rare translations from Google Translate request

Tags: python, nlp, google-translate

For my Bachelors Degree, I am working on a statistical machine translator. Currently, I need a dictionary of English words with all their possible translations. For example:

```
[EN] Food -> [RO] Mancare
```

or

```
[EN] Food -> [RO] Hrana
```

To build the dictionary I need, I adapted a python script (original [here](https://github.com/mouuff/Google-Translate-API/blob/master/python/GoogleTranslate.py)) that takes every word from a list of English words and sends it to google translate, then writes the result in a file. However, I only receive one result per word, the most common translation.

How can I receive the uncommon and rare translations? The Google translate website lists other possible translations, but they do not appear in my result. The [link used in the script](https://translate.google.com/m?hl=ro&sl=en&q=food) is different from the regular Google Translate. I tried sending the request to the regular Google Translate link, but the return page doesn't contain the information I need.

Alternatively, do you know an already existing English - Romanian dictionary with multiple possible translations per word?

Thank you!

This is my Google Translate script:

```
    import urllib2

def translate(word, sourceLanguage, targetLanguage):
    agents = {'User-Agent':"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30)"}
    before_trans = 'class="t0">'
    link = "http://translate.google.com/m?hl=%s&sl=%s&q=%s" % (targetLanguage, sourceLanguage, word)
    request = urllib2.Request(link, headers=agents)
    page = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    result = page[page.find(before_trans)+len(before_trans):]
    result = result.split("<")[0]
    return (result,page)

def main():
    englishWords = open('englishWords.txt', 'r')
    romanianWords = open('romanianWords.txt', 'w')
    studyHTML = open('studyHTML.html', 'w')
    studyTXT = open('studyTXT.txt', 'w')
    for englishWord in englishWords:
        translation = translate(englishWord, 'en', 'ro')
        romanianWord = translation[0]
        page = translation[1]
        if romanianWord != "d>":
            romanianWords.write(romanianWord)
            romanianWords.write("\n")
            studyHTML.write(page)
            studyTXT.write(page)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Example of what I'm trying to get:

```
Food: Mancare, Hrana, Aliment
Car: Masina, Autovehicul
Cat: Pisica, Felina
```

Comment: There is something called grammar. You can't just translate word by word and expect a useable result. You are wasting your time with this approach.

Comment: How can a grammar help me in this case? I am not looking for different forms of a stem, I am looking to get multiple possible translations of my word. Think of them as synonyms of the translated word, although this may not necessarily be the case.

Comment: I'm just telling you that translating word by word won't work because grammar (and context) applies on translation.

Comment: https://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=mt&sl=en&tl=ro&hl=en&q=test this URL will give what you asked for, hope its useful. Its in JSON format.

Comment: Yes, I know. I approached this problem differently. I have another script that handles this. What I am trying to do is this. I have an English sentence. I split it in words and translate every word, into each possible translation. The script mentioned earlier generates possible grammatically correct forms of the word. Using these words, I generate with them the sentences that are structurally correct. I then use an interpolation model, bigrams and unigrams, to calculate which of these sentences is the most probable.

Comment: @Havenard, that you!